# Symfony 2 twig {{ dump(var) }} doesn't work. Twig debug

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I had to dump data in twig template.

Everyone say to use `{{ dump(var) }}` but that wasn't working in my case. I was searching for answer for few hours why `{{ dump(var) }}` doesn't work.

It's not about not setting debug mode on (like someone suggested). I solved this by accident by doing:
**`{% dump var %}`**

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

`New in version 1.5: The dump function was added in Twig 1.5.`

You are probably using an old version of TWIG

Check it with this: `{{ constant('Twig_Environment::VERSION') }}`

For older Twig versions use: `{% debug var %}`

Comment: I am using `SF2.6.0` which uses >`Twig 1.12` My twig version is: `1.16.1-DEV`. I love this standard -1 with no comment for ppl making posts. Such a nice tradition.

Comment: It's not me ;-)  think it could be a problem `Symfony 2.6-BETA(2)` and `1.16.1-DEV`. On `Symfony 2.5.7` and `Twig 1.16.2` everything ok.

Comment: The -1 probably come from the fact your post isn't a question but almost an answer, and it doesn't respect the MCVE principle (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remove the 'answer' part of your post, then repost it as an answer ;)

Comment: Yeah you need to answer your own question as an **answer** and then accept it.